# "excel" find how many records per day

Tags: excel

I have a fairly large table - one column is an iso-8601 time the next is a date formateed column with the date extracted as yyyy-mm-dd.
I'd like to find out how many records in the excel sheet are for each day on average, partitioned for each month.

So input sheet data is like this:
record1 2022-06-22
record2 2022-06-22
:
record 917 2022-06-15
:
record 670507 2022-01-01

the date is formatted as an actual date value.

I'd like the output to look like this:
average hits per day overall: 1234 (but the real number 1234 is an example)
hits for 2022-06-22 1234
hits for 2022-06021 2345
:

I don't know where to start with this in Excel.

I don't want to run on the database because it is production and it's busy enough.

Comment: `countif` on the date?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look for the pivot table feature in Excel that helps to create such “views” by drag and drop.